# How can l use Entity Framework without App.config

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

I want to use Entity Framework without `app.config` file.

I want to define a string variable `Connection String` in my code and use that to connect to the database.

Please show me the way if it is possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're not mentioning what approach you're using (database-first, model-first, code-first) - but basically, in the end, you need to define a string variable and assign it a valid EF connection string

```
string myConnectionString = "...(define a valid EF connection string here)......";
```

Example for database-first approach:

```
string myConnectionString = @"metadata=.\Model1.csdl|.\Model1.ssdl|.\Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string="";data source=.;initial catalog=test;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework""";
```

and then use that to create your `ObjectContext` (database- and model-first) or `DbContext` (code-first)

```
using(ObjectContext ctx = new ObjectContext(myConnectionString))
{
    // do your EF magic here.....
}
```

But quite honestly - I think this is a **really bad idea** since this makes it **impossible** for you to move your application to another machine - no one else can install and run this, since the connection string is hard-coded into your C# code..... the whole point of having config files is so that you can change / adapt things like connection strings so that they are **not** tied to a single machine/location but can be adapted to the particular needs of a given user / customer....

Comment: +1 although... I get a trickle of regular work due to hard-coded database connection info, so maybe I should support doing this sort of thing!

Comment: where do you Handel myConnectionString.when i use this i get error

Comment: While hard-coding the connection information may not be a good idea, there may be situations where it is not possible to use a config file.  I've come across one: The class library I'm writing will be called by a Dynamics CRM application which cannot use a config file - the configuration settings must be passed into the constructor of the class.

Comment: @SimonTewsi: true - but those are very rare edge cases - right?

Comment: Rare maybe, but sometimes you need to pass the connection information in from another configuration source, so it's valuable to know how to do this.

Comment: We store our settings in the registry, and so we read from the registry and pass it into this constructor.

Comment: I'm using your advice but am running into an issue.  Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23656542/entity-framework-6-10-and-database-first-with-hard-coded-connection-string if you get a chance.

Comment: For me, this is useful in testing.  I can materialize the entity but the navigation properties fail when there's not a connection string configuration.  Any idea why?

Comment: You migt also want to use a connection string builder such as SqlConnectionStringBuilder to get the connection string