# Entity Framework 6 with DbUp

Tags: entity-framework-6

Is there a way to use Entity Framework 6 with [DbUp](https://dbup.github.io/) without having 2 connection strings?

The problem is EF uses a conn string with a bunch of meta data for locating the model that DbUp doesn't like - it expects a simple conn string.

And EF doesn't run without all the meta data.

I could have 2 different connection strings but that seems just wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity Framework - Database First without config](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14983882/entity-framework-database-first-without-config)

Comment: If you modify the approach in the duplicate by using the connection string from your config file you have achieved what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Code Based Modelling (Code "First") - that only uses the standard ADO.NET connection string